# How to dd an object to the JList and show member of the object on the list interface to the user?

Tags: java, swing

I have an ArrayList of object which is type of the cd. I want to add all the objects to the JList and show the field of name to the user. I can add the String type to the JList but what about specific field of the object?

CD is:

```
class CD{
    public CD(String n){name = n;}
    private String name;
    public String getName(){return name;}
    public void setName(String n){name = n;}
}
```

ArrayList is:

```
ArrayList<CD> myList = new ArrayList<CD>();
```

And now I want to add myList to a JList:

```
JList list = new JList(myList);
panel.add(list);
JScrollPane scrol = new JScrollPane(list);
frame.add(scrol,BorderLayout.EAST);
frame.add(panel);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

First of all, is this way correct? Secondly how can I show the user name field of the object in the list? my desired interface is :

[image]

The left side is the name of my object!
Thanks in advance.
Bernard

Comment: i understand swing. i don't understand the question.

Comment: I think the code that you posted is incorrect (uncompilable)... // EDIT: Ok, maybe it is correct.

Comment: @user1329572 so you don't understand swing.

Comment: @m4tx yes the code is just a sample. Imagine you have an object how to add it to the Jlist and then show one of its field.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a custom renderer based on the DefaultListCellRenderer:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestJList {

    class CD {
        public CD(String n) {
            name = n;
        }

        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String n) {
            name = n;
        }
    }

    protected void initUI() {
        List<CD> cds = new ArrayList<CD>();
        cds.add(new CD("MJ - Bad"));
        cds.add(new CD("Mozart - Concerto 123"));
        cds.add(new CD("Nadeah - Odile"));
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestJList.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JList list = new JList(new Vector<CD>(cds));
        list.setVisibleRowCount(10);
        list.setCellRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                Component renderer = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
                if (renderer instanceof JLabel && value instanceof CD) {
                    // Here value will be of the Type 'CD'
                    ((JLabel) renderer).setText(((CD) value).getName());
                }
                return renderer;
            }
        });
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(list));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestJList().initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lo, now i can understand where we set the value must show on the list. Great job mate.

Comment: @Bernard You are welcome. Of course, feel free to do whatever you want inside the method `getListCellRendererComponent` and set whatever text you want. You can also implement yourself `ListCellRendererComponent` and choose to return whatever component you prefer (you could have a complex JPanel with embedded labels, images, etc...)

Answer (score 3):

I think that if you want to work with the `CD` class directly with `JList`, you'll need to write your own renderer, that will work with `CD` class. The renderer may extend the `JLabel` and display the contents of the `name` field.

There's also other way: `for()` that iterates over the `ArrayList` and adds only the `name` field to the `DefaultListRenderer`. The way that you'll do it is your choice.

You can also add `ListSelectionListener` to show the album details of the selected list item.

All that you need to know is here:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#selection

// Thanks for kleopatra :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm pretty new to swing and this example is complex. I can't understand it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html

Comment: Yeah, renderers in Swing are a bit difficult to understand. Did you see this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer ? I think there's all info that you need to create and use your rendererer. Btw., you can also override the toString() method, like @James said.

Comment: @m4tx _also override the toString()_ - while that's possible, it's a no-no-ever in Swing, creating and showing a string representation from an arbitrary object is the exclusive task of a renderer. The general rule here is: never-ever solve visual problems in the data realm. If you don't like the default's toString, implement a custom renderer which uses the property you want.

Comment: so the answer is correct [1] , the comment is not :-) [1] except the part _extend JLabel_ - don't: instead implement a renderer which _uses_ a JLabel, best a DefaultListRenderer (which takes care of all the visual intricacies)

Answer (score 0):

There is no constructor for JList that takes an ArrayList, however you can use a Vector or an Array (and ArrayList can easily be converted to an Array).

to display what you want to the user, You could use a custom renderer. Alternatively you could just override the toString() method of CD which, if I recall correctly, is the default method to use to determine what to show.

Comment: Sorry I'm so new to Java. you mean I override the toString in CD class?which is 

public String toString(){
  return getTitle();
}

Comment: @Bernard while overriding toString() will fix your problem, it is not a maintainable solution and it is not recommended to rely on such thing, since this would mean that you tightly couple your UI to your model. The "best" way is to use a renderer.