# Show object members inside JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listcellrenderer

I have a list of objects using the default list model, like so:

```
public static DefaultListModel<Loan> loans = new DefaultListModel<Loan>();
```

My Swing application looks like this:

[image: Image of my swing application]

When the Add button is clicked, it creates a Loan object and adds that object to the `DefaultListModel`, like so:

```
addLoan.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Loan loan = Calculator.createLoan(
                Double.parseDouble(loanAmount.getText()),
                Double.parseDouble(interestRate.getText()),
                Double.parseDouble(term.getText())
        );

        Calculator.addALoan(loan); 
    }
});
```

With my code now, the objects actually appear in the `JScrollPane` fine. You can see below:

```
JList loanList = new JList(Calculator.loans);
loans = new javax.swing.JScrollPane(loanList);
```

The above code happens in my `init` method. This is what I see on the frontend:

[image]

I want to tab it out and show each of the members inside that box (scroll pane). A Loan object consists of amount, interest rate and term. I tried something similar to ([How to dd an object to the JList and show member of the object on the list interface to the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478661/how-to-dd-an-object-to-the-jlist-and-show-member-of-the-object-on-the-list-inter)) but I am confused on how the renderer in the accepted answer shows up.

Comment: The default renderer for a JList just invokes the `toString()` method of the object in the `ListModel`. When you have multiple columns of data you should be using a `JTable`. See the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information. If you want to store a `Loan` object in your `TableModel`, then you can create a custom `TableModel`. See:: [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for a step-by-step example on how this can be done.

Comment: (1-) Note: you were given the above advice over two weeks ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68263118/display-arraylist-of-objects-in-jlist.

Comment: @camickr Apologies I didnt notice this was asked before by me. I didn't get a sufficient answer regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the result of Swing’s default behavior.  Swing is calling [toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) on each Loan object.

You can override that method to return something suitable for display:

```
public class Loan {
    // (property methods)

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%12s    %6s    %,.1f years",
            NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(
                getAmount()),
            NumberFormat.getPercentInstance().format(
                getInterestRate() / 100),
            getTerm());
    }
}
```

Since JList uses a proportional width font on most platforms, the values from the loan objects probably won’t line up with each other.  To address that, remove your JList, remove your list model, and instead subclass AbstractTableModel and use a JTable as camickr suggested.

Comment: I'll just mention that you can use a monospaced font in a JList.  However, I agree with everyone that a JTable and TableModel are the correct choices for the code in the question.